# Does AUTOCOMMIT_DDL work on an ABAP-based system, non HANA system?

Tags: sql, abap, hana

In an ABAP-based system, SET TRANSACTION AUTOCOMMIT DDL Statement Specifies the auto commit property for DDL statements specific to the session.

`SET TRANSACTION AUTOCOMMIT DDL ON;`

However, I see in the [note 2560888 - SAP HANA 'SET TRANSACTION' SQL calls are no longer permitted](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2560888):

> Solution 
> There are the following functions in the class `CL_SQL_CONNECTION` that can be used instead: 
> `AUTOCOMMIT_DDL`

So, does anyone know if `AUTOCOMMIT_DDL` works on an ABAP-based system, non-Hana system please?

Answer (score 0):

`AUTOCOMMIT DDL` is a database session setting specific to SAP HANA. Other DBMS, e.g. Oracle don’t support DDL without implicit commits.